# Matrix multiplication but only between specific rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have three two matrices `A` and `B`, the matrix product I want is `diagonal(A.B.A^T)`, where `A^T` is transpose of a matrix. The dimensions of the matrices are as follows

```
A - (2^n, n) 
B - (n, n)
```

where is `n` is any natural number.

I want first row slice of matrix `A` to be multiplied with matrix `B` and their product is multiplied with first column of matrix `A^T`. I don't want the full product of `A.B.A^T` because I only want the diagonal slice.

It seems to me this can be achieved using eisum.

A related question on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224671/evaluate-joint-probability-density-function-of-a-markov-random-field)

Comment: maybe just full product and use numpy.diagonal()

Comment: Too slow, I'm doing way more calculations than I need to. `2^n` grows very big for `n > 10`. Since there is repeated pattern here, I'm hoping that we can use einsum and get rid of the for loop. This product is the core to my experiments and if I have save time, I would save money.

Comment: You can simply get `A.B` trough dot product. Then, since you only want the diagonal, multiply the previous result elementwise by `A` and do a sum reduction: `(A@B*A).sum(1)`

Comment: Use linked dup target one for a faster one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it with einsum

```
np.random.seed(1)

A = np.random.randint(0,10,(8,4))
B = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,4))

# brute force for reference
np.diag(A@B@A.T)
# array([3830,  233, 2835,  958, 3706, 1273, 5478,  934])

# more economical
np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',A,B,A)
# array([3830,  233, 2835,  958, 3706, 1273, 5478,  934])
```

Comment: As the size grows larger the speedup is growing larger, seeing 10x-30x speedups. Thank you. Paul and `einsum` FTW.